# Swift: Multiply two Numerics

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, numeric

```
protocol DArray: Sequence where Element: Numeric {
    var elements: [Element] { get set }
    subscript(index: Int) -> Element { get set }
    static func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

struct Vector<Element: Numeric>: DArray {
    var elements: [Element]

    init(_ elements: [Element] = []) {
        self.elements = elements
    }

    ...

    static func *<T: DArray>(lhs: Self, rhs: T) -> Self {
        var v = lhs
        var result: Self
        for (i, element) in rhs.enumerated() {
            let e = v[i]
            let r = element * e
            // Cannot convert value of type 'Element' (generic parameter of generic struct 'Vector') to expected argument type 'T.Element' (associated type of protocol 'Sequence')
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

To the `Numeric` protocol, the documentation says:

> The Numeric protocol provides a suitable basis for arithmetic on
>   scalar values, such as integers and floating-point numbers. You can
>   write generic methods that operate on any numeric type in the standard
>   library by using the Numeric protocol as a generic constraint.

So I chose the Numeric protocol as a generic constraint for the Element type as well as for T.Element. Although both `e` and `element` conform to the `Numeric` protocol I can't multiply them (getting the error message: *Cannot convert value of type 'Element' (generic parameter of generic struct 'Vector') to expected argument type 'T.Element' (associated type of protocol 'Sequence')*). How do I do that?

Comment: Yes, you can multiply two `Numeric`s together, but they have to be the same `Numeric`. `Int` and `Double` are both `Numeric`, but you can't multiply them. Do you want a `Vector<Double> * Vector<Int>` to produce a `Vector<Double>`, while a `Vector<Int> * Vector<Double>` to produce a `Vector<Int>`? The latter does not make much sense to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because multiplication is commutative, it doesn't make sense to define the output type of `*` to be either of the operands' types. Instead, you could allow for all `DArray`s to be initializable with their elements.

```swift
protocol DArray: Sequence where Element: Numeric {
  var elements: [Element] { get set }
  init<Elements: Sequence>(_: Elements) where Elements.Element == Element
}

extension Vector {
  init<Elements: Sequence>(_ elements: Elements) where Elements.Element == Element {
    self.init( Array(elements) )
  }
}
```

And then, define the operator like this:

```
extension DArray {
  static func * <Parameter1: DArray, Output: DArray>(
    dArray0: Self, dArray1: Parameter1
  ) -> Output
  where Parameter1.Element == Element, Output.Element == Element {
    multiply(dArray0, dArray1)
  }

  static func * (dArray0: Self, dArray1: Self) -> Self {
    multiply(dArray0, dArray1)
  }

  private static func multiply<Parameter0: DArray, Parameter1: DArray, Output: DArray>(
    _ dArray0: Parameter0, _ dArray1: Parameter1
  ) -> Output
  where Parameter0.Element == Parameter1.Element, Parameter1.Element == Output.Element {
    .init( zip(dArray0, dArray1).map(*) )
  }
}
```

That way, you can explicitly type the result, as you please, and have an overload for the case where it makes sense to use implicit typing.

```swift
struct : DArray, IteratorProtocol {
  mutating func next() -> Int? { nil }

  var elements: [Element] = []

  init<Elements: Sequence>(_ elements: Elements) where Elements.Element == Element { }
}


( Vector() * ([]) ) as Vector
( Vector() * ([]) ) as 
( ([]) * Vector() ) as Vector
( ([]) * Vector() ) as 

let vector: Vector = ( Vector() * ([]) )
let :  = ( ([]) * Vector() )

Vector([1]) * Vector()
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Sweeper mentioned you can multiply only the same `Numeric`s.

So you have to specify that in your function using `where` clause:

```
static func * <T: DArray> (lhs: Vector<Element>, rhs: T) -> Vector<Element> where T.Element == Element {
    let result = zip(lhs, rhs).map { lhs, rhs in
        lhs * rhs
    }
    return Vector(result)
}
```

Comment: Ah... Why did I assume the OP wanted to multiply `DArray` of _different_ types! OP could very well have meant to write this instead, couldn't they?

Comment: Well I wasn't too aware of not being able to multiply two different numerics, but that's what I wanted @user28434